# Code still runs though it has been deleted

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a an app. Form 1 has a button which was set to open an instance of form2. I got some funny behaviour with the form reopening itself. So i deleted the code from that button on form1. Still when i click on that button, its opening the form2. Any idea??

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't recompile the app? There was an error when you recompiled so you still have the old version?

Comment: Or may be you are running in release mode instead of debug

Comment: Yeah when i debug it, it do like that

Comment: Delete all DLL from bin folder and build again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Clean, then rebuild the project.

Comment: *Try this* is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thats i get as a good answer. It worked thanks.